# How do disabled Form Actions work in outlook; specifically: disabling reply-all?

Tags: vba, outlook, smtp

According To [Scott Hanselman's blog post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-easily-disable-reply-to-all-and-forward-in-outlook) you can disable "reply-all" in your emails with a macro. I have tested this and it is also possible to disable this action with the developer tools in that are built into outlooks form editor.

It obviously only works in Outlook desktop to outlook desktop scenarios. However, when I inspect the email body or use outlookspy I can't see any thing in the message or exchange responses that would indicate that "reply-all" is disabled.

How is it possible for the receiver's client to know that reply-all is disabled? I expected some header, hidden attachment or even some trickery of exchange server, but I can't seem to find anything that explains what could be happening.  I would like to replicate this functionality (in my internal corporate network) making "reply"/"reply-all"/"forward" disabled for all of our automated messages, truly making "no-reply" mean NO REPLY.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling various actions on a message only works locally - the recipients do not see that information and their email client would be under no obligation to honor that request even if it was present.

You can of course use Information Right Management (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/information-rights-management?view=exchserver-2019), but it is not quite the same.

Comment: but it does work on any outlook desktop client. so I am wondering how that works, and how it is implemented.  I don't need it to be "guaranteed", but It does work so I am wondering how it works.  it can't be "magic". there must be some protocol or cookie or something that is used to transmit the data as shown in the blog post i referenced

Comment: If the message is sent in the RTF format (winmail.dat attachment), all MAPI properties are preserved. Try to CC a Gmail address on your message and then look at its MIME source in the Gmail Inbox.